# Nokia N900 - Meego Linux - xterminal - shell script - keep process alive

Tags: linux, shell, process, terminal, keep-alive

I need a program in Nokia N900 - Meego Linux - to be always on if it dies it must restart by itself how do i do it?

I would like to use it on '*x11vnc*'

also maybe start the process again if its killed by any other process, restarting itself again

Answer (score 9):

Add your process to /etc/inittab, and let init restart your process when it terminates.

I.e.

```
mp:2345:respawn:/usr/app/bin/my_process
```

See inittab(5) for details.

(Credit goes to Lew Pitcher, http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/process-alive-ftopict10675.html)

Answer (score 3):

Using inittab as suggested by blinry is good when you have root access.

When you don't have root access, you can run a shell in screen and have it do this:

```
$ while true; do run_program; done
```

This is assuming that your "run_program" script does not go into the background otherwise the loop will keep on spawning instances of "run_program" indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [daemon](http://libslack.org/daemon/manpages/daemon.1.html), which I installed from apt-get.  It has an argument -r that should restart my command if it dies.  So my final command ended up being:

```
daemon -u www-data -n arbitrary_name -r -X "ffmpeg blah blah blah"
```